# não estou conseguindo salvar uma edição de dados com php e mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Salvar funcionando corretamente

```
<?php include "conectar.php";
$nome="$_POST[nome]";
$sobrenome="$_POST[sobrenome]";
$email="$_POST[email]";
$cpf="$_POST[cpf]";
$dddcel="$_POST[dddcel]";
$cel="$_POST[cel]";
$dddtel="$_POST[dddtel]";
$tel="$_POST[tel]";
$nasc="$_POST[nasc]";

$sql->query ("insert into dados(nome, sobrenome, email, cpf, dddcel, cel, dddtel, tel, nasc) values ('$nome', '$sobrenome', '$email', '$cpf', '$dddcel', '$cel', '$dddtel', '$tel', '$nasc')");

header("Location: listar.php");
?>
```

E este é o uptade que não esta funcionando:

```
<?php 
include "conectar.php";   //inlui o conectar(endereco do banco)
$nome=$_POST["nome"];
$sobrenome=$_POST["sobrenome"];
$email=$_POST["email"];
$cpf=$_POST["cpf"];
$dddcel=$_POST["dddcel"];
$cel=$_POST["cel"];
$dddtel=$_POST["dddtel"];
$tel=$_POST["tel"];
$nasc=$_POST["nasc"];

$sql->query("UPDATE dados SET nome ='$nome', sobrenome ='$sobrenome', email = '$email', cpf = '$cpf', dddcel = '$dddcel', cel = '$cel', dddtel = '$dddtel', tel = '$tel', nasc = '$nasc' where cod = $cod");

header("Location: listar.php");
?>
```

Comment: De onde vem a variável `$cod`? Ela contém valor?

Comment: Tens a sintaxe trocada: `$nome="$_POST[nome]";` deve ser `$nome=$_POST["nome"];` em todas as variáveis.

Comment: Não existe nenhuma mensagem de erro? Com isso ficaria mais fácil pra gente te ajudar.

Answer (score 0):

A sintaxe está errada:

Errado

```
$nome="$_POST[nome]";
```

Certo

```
$nome = $_POST["nome"];
```

Não entendi porque você disse que o "Salvar" está funcionando, sendo que a sintaxe está errada.

Comment: Acho que ai foi só erro de digitação dele aqui, pois onde tem isso é no arquivo onde ele diz que funciona. o.O

Comment: No primeiro código existe a possibilidade de ter salvado tudo como STRING no banco de dados(SE AS COLUNAS ESTIVEREM SETADAS PARA RECEBER STRING), se não aconteceu isso deu erro. No segundo faltou a variável '$cod'.